# Как понять внутри цикла WordPress и снаружи цикла?

Tags: wordpress

Прочитал эту статью:https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts
На 8 пункте написано:

Код нужно **использовать внутри Цикла WordPress,** где переменная $post->ID:

**Как понять внутри Цикла WordPress?**

```js
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title() ?>
<?php the_content();?>

// ********************************************************
// ********* Вот это место внутри цикла WordPress? ********
// ********************************************************

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_119/the-loop.html

Comment: да я читал это, там не написано как понять внутри цикла или нет. написано пару сырых предложений в конце статьи,  но там сам автор сказал, что много говорить не буду на эту тему ,так как это совсем уже другая история. Но я так и не понял суть.

Comment: @Black_Viper, обратите внимание на первую строку, в ней как раз и стартует цикл вывода постов. Отмеченное вами место внутри цикла, но циклы разные бывают и хорошо бы понимать не только факт нахождения в цикле, но и в каком именно цикле вы находитесь. В приведенном вами примере двоеточия, endif и пр - это альтернативный синтаксис управляющих структур в php. По хорошему надо про это почитать, тк в циклах wp это сплошь и рядом встречается.